JavaScript Execution Issue after HTML Replacement
I'm currently facing an issue with JavaScript execution after dynamically replacing the HTML content in my web application using JavaScript.
CURRENT FUNCTION:
function insertHTML(decodedData) {
    // Method 1 Parse decoded HTML
    const decodedHTML = decodedData;
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(decodedHTML, 'text/html');
    document.documentElement.replaceWith(doc.documentElement);

    // Method 2 Replace current document 
    document.open();
    document.write(decodedHTML);
    document.close();

}

EXPECTED CODE In decodedData variable:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/fontawesome.min.css"/>
<title>Title of Page</title>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body class="dark-theme">
<script>
    var notify = {
        timeout: "3000",
    }
</script>
<div class="layout">Content Here</div>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-migrate.js"></script>

<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
<script>
        // Color Switcher
        $(".color-switcher").on('click', function () {
            "use strict"
            $("body").toggleClass("dark-theme");
            var url = '/theme-mode';
            $.get(url)
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>

ISSUE:
It does not execute the JavaScript however the CSS works.

I pass decoded HTML string it has full page content from (!DOCTYPE To the ).
I replace the entire current document's HTML content and will execute all the new JavaScript files and code which is replaced.


Consider using jquery load because that automatically runs scripts in the loaded content unlike the technique you are using now.

ISSUE: It does not execute the JavaScript however the CSS works. Please, does this happen after dynamically replacing the HTML content?

Thanks, I found the solution using the append and separating the head, body tags and making them clean removing script tags and then parsing them. At the last we have to append the scripts by creating elements. All scripts are working but only jQuery does not work.
